# Display "correct banner and color" for 3 seconds after clicking right answer then hidding them forever

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I have been trying to do and search for this for a lot of time but the people use other types of outputs or Jquery and I am just lerning Javascript.

Im trying to display a banner that says **"correct"** and color the button green after clicking the "correct button" and **after 3 sec** disappear the message and place the color of the button as before! I tried using SetInterval() or SetTime() functions but i cannot find anywhere how to display the message and color of the button for 3 seconds and not showing the changes again. That way another person can try answering the question without any hints (really frustrated after a couple of hours jaja).

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Trivia!</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Trivia!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="section">
            <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
            <hr>

            <h3> Which is the most expensive car in the world?</h3>


            **<p id="veredict" class="hide"> CORRECT!</p>**
            <p id="veredict_2" class="hide"> INCORRECT!</p>

            <button onclick="submitButtonStyle(this)" id= "correct" class="main_butt opt1"> Bugatti La Voiture Noire</button>

            <button onclick="submitButtonStyle1(this)"id= "incorrect1" class="main_butt opt2">  Pagani Zonda HP Barchetta</button>

            <button onclick="submitButtonStyle2(this)" id= "incorrect2" class="main_butt opt3"> Rolls Royce Sweptail</button>

            <button onclick="submitButtonStyle3(this)" id= "incorrect3" class="main_butt opt4"> Lamborghini Veneno Roadster</button>


        <div class="section">
            <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
            <hr>

        </div>

    </div>

       <script>


        **let button = document.querySelector('#correct');
        let msg = document.querySelector('#veredict');

        button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        msg.classList.toggle('reveal');**

        })


        let button2 = document.querySelector('#incorrect1');
        let msg1 = document.querySelector('#veredict_2');

        button2.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            msg1.classList.toggle('reveal');
        })

        let button3 = document.querySelector('#incorrect2');
        let msg2 = document.querySelector('#veredict_2');

        button3.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            msg2.classList.toggle('reveal');
        })


        let button4 = document.querySelector('#incorrect3');
        let msg3 = document.querySelector('#veredict_2');

        button4.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            msg3.classList.toggle('reveal');
        })

        **function submitButtonStyle(_this) {
        _this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }**

        function submitButtonStyle1(_this) {
         _this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }


        function submitButtonStyle2(_this) {
         _this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }

        function submitButtonStyle3(_this) {
         _this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

I really appreciate the help people!! How can I achieve this using Javascript? Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

giving the same id to multiple elements is not the right way. add a class `wrong`  (or any suitable class) for the wrong answers and `right` for the right answer to the buttons.

then add an eventLinsterner to each wrong buttons element using `querySelectorAll` with `forEach` to toggle the `hide` class of the banner. Then add a `setTimeout` function to hide the banner after the specific amount.
Same with the `right` button. the `right` button will only need `querySelector` to add the eventListener.

Here is the working example...

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".incorrect").forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    document.getElementById("veredict_2").classList.toggle("hide");
    setTimeout(hideBanners, 3000);
  });
});

document.querySelector(".correct").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  document.getElementById("veredict").classList.toggle("hide");
  setTimeout(hideBanners, 3000);
});

const hideBanners = (e) => {
  document.getElementById("veredict").classList.add("hide");
  document.getElementById("veredict_2").classList.add("hide");
};
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 40%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}

.banner.right {
  background-color: green;
}

.banner.wrong {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
<hr>

<h3> Which is the most expensive car in the world?</h3>

**<p id="veredict" class="hide banner right"> CORRECT!</p>**
<p id="veredict_2" class="hide banner wrong"> INCORRECT!</p>

**<button class="correct main_butt opt1"> Bugatti La Voiture Noire</button>**

<button class="incorrect main_butt opt2"> Pagani Zonda HP Barchetta</button>

<button class="incorrect main_butt opt3"> Rolls Royce Sweptail</button>

<button class="incorrect main_butt opt4"> Lamborghini Veneno Roadster</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals). It should be

```
  msg.classList.add("reveal");

  setTimeout(() => {
    msg.classList.remove("reveal");
  }, 3000);
```

[Codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-bash-3nmlr?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 1):

As Rajiv mentions, using the same id for multiple elements causes problems. Here is another approach where you only need to assign an id to the correct answer button.

```html
<div class="container">

    <section>

        <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
        <h3> Which is the most expensive car in the world?</h3>

        <!--Assuming "hide" class is "visibility: hidden"-->
        <p id="veredict" class="hide"> CORRECT!</p>
        <p id="veredict_2" class="hide"> INCORRECT!</p>

        <button id="correct" class="main_butt opt1"> Bugatti La Voiture Noire</button>
        <button class="main_butt opt2">  Pagani Zonda HP Barchetta</button>
        <button class="main_butt opt3"> Rolls Royce Sweptail</button>
        <button class="main_butt opt4"> Lamborghini Veneno Roadster</button>

    </section>

</div>
```

```js
function showStatus() {
    "use strict";

    //Get section.
    const section = document.querySelector("section");

    //Monitor for clicks.
    section.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

        //Get messages.
        const verdict = document.getElementById("veredict");
        const verdict2 = document.getElementById("veredict_2");

        //Check if target is button.
        if (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {

            //If correct answer, show correct message.
            //If other answer, show incorrect message.
            if (event.target.id === "correct") {
                verdict.style.visibility = "visible";
                setTimeout(function () {
                    verdict.style.visibility = "hidden";
                }, 3000);
            } else {
                verdict2.style.visibility = "visible";
                setTimeout(function () {
                    verdict2.style.visibility = "hidden";
                }, 3000);
            }
        }
    });
}

showStatus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `setTimeout` is right to resolve this question. Painting button to green after clicking then `setTimeout` which removes the green color and the answer is executed after 3 seconds.

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.reveal {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Trivia!</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Trivia!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="section">
            <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
            <hr>

            <h3> Which is the most expensive car in the world?</h3>


            <p id="veredict" class="hide"> CORRECT!</p>
            <p id="veredict_2" class="hide"> INCORRECT!</p>

            <button onclick="submitButtonStyle(this)" id= "correct" class="main_butt opt1"> Bugatti La Voiture Noire</button>

            <button onclick="submitButtonStyle1(this)"id= "incorrect1" class="main_butt opt2">  Pagani Zonda HP Barchetta</button>

            <button onclick="submitButtonStyle2(this)" id= "incorrect2" class="main_butt opt3"> Rolls Royce Sweptail</button>

            <button onclick="submitButtonStyle3(this)" id= "incorrect3" class="main_butt opt4"> Lamborghini Veneno Roadster</button>


        <div class="section">
            <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
            <hr>

        </div>

    </div>

       <script>


        let button = document.querySelector('#correct');
        let msg = document.querySelector('#veredict');
/*
        function painting() {
        return new Promise (() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
              submitButtonStyle(button);              
              msg.style.display = 'block';
              }, 1000);
        })
        }
            
        function turnOff() { 
        return new Promise(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
            button.removeAttribute('style'); 
            msg.style.display = 'none';
            }, 1500)
        })
        }
        
        async function startPaint() {
              return await painting()
              .then(turnOff());              
            }
*/          
        button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        msg.classList.toggle('reveal');
        
        //painting and showing green button
        submitButtonStyle(button);   
        msg.style.display = 'block';
        
        //removing green and answer after 3 seconds
        setTimeout(() => {
          msg.classList.toggle('hide');
          button.removeAttribute('style'); 
          msg.style.display = 'none';
        }, 3000)
        })


        let button2 = document.querySelector('#incorrect1');
        let msg1 = document.querySelector('#veredict_2');

        button2.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            msg1.classList.toggle('reveal');
        })

        let button3 = document.querySelector('#incorrect2');
        let msg2 = document.querySelector('#veredict_2');

        button3.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            msg2.classList.toggle('reveal');
        })


        let button4 = document.querySelector('#incorrect3');
        let msg3 = document.querySelector('#veredict_2');

        button4.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            msg3.classList.toggle('reveal');
        })

        function submitButtonStyle(_this) {
        _this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }

        function submitButtonStyle1(_this) {
         _this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }


        function submitButtonStyle2(_this) {
         _this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }

        function submitButtonStyle3(_this) {
         _this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this the buttons function like that :-

```
 let button1 = document.getElementById('correct');
 let msg = document.getElementById('veredict');

 button1.addEventListener('click',function(){
   msg.style.display = 'block'
  setTimeout(function(){
    msg.style.display = 'none'
  },3000) 
 })
```